# How do I set option to connect to FortiManager in Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-vm

I am new to Azure. I am using Terraform to deploy Azure virtual machines from marketplace images. The Azure Virtual Machine I'm deploying is a FortiGate firewall.

I want it to connect to FortiManager later on. How do I define this in terraform? I want to be able to use FortiManager IP Address and Serial Number.

Manually creating the firewall from Azure Marketplace looks like this:

[image]

Code:

```
resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine" "fgtvm" {
  name                 = var.fgt.name
  resource_group_name  = var.rg_name
  location             = var.location

  vm_size              = var.fgt.size
  zones                = var.fgt.zones

  admin_username       = "adminuser"
  admin_password       = "123password"

  network_interface_id = azurerm_network_interface.fgt_nic.id
  
  storage_image_reference {
    publisher = var.fgt.image.publisher
    offer     = var.fgt.image.offer
    sku       = var.fgt.image.sku
    version   = var.fgt.image.version
  }

  plan {
    name      = var.fgt.image.sku
    publisher = var.fgt.image.publisher
    product   = var.fgt.image.offer
  }


  os_disk {
    caching               = var.fgt.os_disk.caching
    storage_account_type  = var.fgt.os_disk.storage_account_type
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to connect to FortiManager later. I want to be able to use FortiManager IP Address and Serial Number.

You can make use of below sample cmdlet for Ip address

```c
provider "fortimanager" 
  hostname     = "10.50.0.132/24"
  username     = "admin"
  password     = "SecurePassw0rd"
  insecure     = "true"
 
  scopetype    = "vdomtest"
  adom         = "root"
}
 
terraform {
  required_providers {
    fortimanager = {
      source  = "fortinetdev/fortimanager"
    }
  }
}
```

***Reference***: [Docs overview | fortinetdev/fortios | Terraform Registry](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/fortinetdev/fortios/latest/docs#configuration-for-fortimanager)

While creating manually in Fortinet FortiGate next generation firewall you need to set connect fortimanager as NO. once you deployed Fortinet FortiGate use your fortinet Virtual Machine public Ip address to login firewall like below.

[image]

Use this Ip address and open in new tab URL -> click advance -> proceed -> login username and password.  if you want to use FortiManager to manage this FortiGate, ***If you need to use FortiManager IP Address and Serial Number.*** once the FortiGate portal has open you can see serial number in status and main option.

[image]

If you do not see the serial in the console, you need to reboot the Fortigate VM from the Cloud Control Panel. After the reboot, you should see the serial number displayed in the console.

To see FortiGate Ip address ***click interface under Network***

[image]

Reference: [FortiGate deployment guide - Microsoft Entra | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/saas-apps/media/fortigate-ssl-vpn-tutorial/fortigate-deployment-guide-converted)

---

Alternatively, you can make use of [Azure CLI command](https://www.petenetlive.com/kb/article/0001712) as below

```java
config system interface #To visbile ip address
edit ?
get system status       # to see staus of DHCP including serical number
```

Comment: So is there no way we can add the fortiManager serial number and IP adress in terraform beforehand? Because I'm looking to deploy the FortiManager before I deploy the fortGates.

Comment: I did find the the following parameters in the json file from the template:

Comment: "fortiManager": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "no",
            "allowedValues": [
                "yes",
                "no"
            ],
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Connect to FortiManager"
            }
        },

Comment: "fortiManagerIP": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "FortiManager IP or DNS name to connect to on port TCP/541"
            }
        },

Comment: "fortiManagerSerial": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "FortiManager serial number to add the deployed FortiGate into the FortiManager"
            }
        },

Comment: btw, i have 2 diferent terraform repos: one for deploying the fortiManager and one then for deploying the fortiGates.

Comment: yes, there is no way without accessing the fortimanager console you can get the serial number of the fortimanager over software also once after retrieving serial number you can use it for config other depended software like fortianalyazer and fortmanager as per given 
[link](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/fortinetdev/fortios/latest/docs/resources/fortios_logfortianalyzer3_setting)

Comment: So can I use the serial number in the fortiGates using a similar block as in fortiAnalyser?

Comment: yes, you can use  serial number in the fortiGates using a similar block as in fortiAnalyser

Answer (score 0):

the form you can see when deploying from the Marketplace is turned into bootstrap configuration passed to the newly created FGT via instance metadata (user-data). Unfortunately, the [source code](https://github.com/fortinet/azure-templates/blob/ae524a2c8030e83d7572227d9a904ed858ae9358/FortiGate/Active-Active-ELB-ILB/azuredeploy.json#L380) is a bit hard to read due to ARM templates formatting, so often the easiest way to read compiled bootstrap configuration is to actually deploy and check the metadata.

In this case, you need a configuration block like this:

```
config system central-management
  set type fortimanager
  set fmg ${var.fortiManagerIP}
  set serial-number ${var.fortiManagerSerial}
end
```